# Skewed base 10 notation of a number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Every number can be represented as
$$
a_r10^r+a_{r-1}10^{r-1}+\cdots+a_110+a_0
$$
with $-1 \le a_i \le 8$. Where the set $\{a_i: 0\le i \le r\}$ form a complete set of residue classes modulo $10$.

How do I prove this statement?

---

My Thoughts:

Any r-digit number $n=a_ra_{r-1}...a_0$ can be written as $n = a_r10^r+\cdots+a_110+a_0$ with $0 \le a_i \le 9$.

But I cannot think how to prove the above statement. Any hints will be very helpfull.

Comment: Reading the digits right to left, for each occurrence of the digit $(9)$, substitute $(10 - 1)$ and recompute the coefficients.  Do this re-computation one $(9)$ digit at a time.  That is, $189$ goes to $100 + 80 + (10 - 1) = 100 + 90 + -1.$   This then gets re-computed to $100 + 10(10 - 1) + -1 = 200 + 10(-1) + (-1).$

Comment: Notice that each re-computation leaves all digits to the right of the re-computed coefficient unaffected, and removes the $(9)$ coefficient at the location of the re-computation.  Working right to left, with a finite number having a finite number of coefficients that need re-computation, after a finite number of re-computation steps,  all of the $(9)$ coefficients will have to have been eliminated.  There is the minor issue that sometimes, the re-computation will result in adding an extra digit to the left.  For example $900$ goes to $1000 + 100(-1)$.  ...see next comment

Comment: So, you have to demonstrate that the result of having an extra digit added to the left **can not continue indefinitely**.

Comment: Also, depending on how you interpret the question that you posed, you also have to demonstrate that the re-computation is one-to-one (i.e. an injection).  Since the previous comments deal with the issue of the re-computation being a surjection, you would then have that the re-computation is a bijection.